# Eclipse Luna (R): no content assist for Java 8 method references

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Luna Release (4.4.0)
Build id: 20140612-0600

---

I'm using the release version of Eclipse Luna for Java (Java EE), and it seems that there's no content assist for the new Java 8-style *method references*. In the example below, I hit Ctrl-Space after the '::', expecting to see the list of methods available on the class `Match`. Instead I just get some generic template assist, even if I cycle through all the assist menus. Normal content assist on methods work fine, it's just Java 8 method references (::) that don't work.

[image]

Is this supposed to work? If not, why not? By design? Bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this might be Eclipse bug [430656](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=430656).

Method reference content assist does work in some places but not in 'invocation contexts'.

Comment: That bug has been fixed for the 4.4.2 release, due out in Feburary, 2015. It would presumably be in the Mars (4.5) releases, too.

Answer (score 0):

A possible work-around: Eclipse Luna 4.4.0 and 4.4.1 does include support for method reference syntax, but not in the in-line context you're trying. It does work if you declare the method reference as a variable with a specific type, however. Like this:

```
Function<String, Object> methodRef = String::valueOf;
new LinkedList<String>().stream().map(methodRef);
```

In this code, content-assist works correctly at the `::` point.