# Eclipse Java 8 recommendations for :: functions?

Tags: eclipse, java-8

Eclipse gives me content assist on functions. For example `String.` <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> shows me `String.valueOf()`, among others.

With a stream and using `::`, this does not work, however. For example, `new LinkedList<String>().stream().map(String::` <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> does not help me in completing it to `new LinkedList<String>().stream().map(String::valueOf);`.

Is there some option or plugin to enable this? I use Eclipse Luna (4.4.0).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse Luna (R): no content assist for Java 8 method references](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24453083/eclipse-luna-r-no-content-assist-for-java-8-method-references)

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse Luna does include support for method reference syntax, but apparently not in the specific context you're trying. It does work if you declare the method reference as a variable with a specific type, however. Like this:

```
Function<String, Object> methodRef = String::valueOf;
new LinkedList<String>().stream().map(methodRef);
```

In this code, content-assist works correctly at the `::` point. I suspect this is because Eclipse has more information about the types this way (with the type declared in the variable), as opposed to the in-line syntax of your example.

According to [Eclipse bug 430656](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=430656), this has been fixed for the 4.4.2 release, which is due in February, 2015. Before then you could download an early milestone build of 4.4.2