# Eclipse content assist not working when using Method reference inside Stream.map

Tags: java, eclipse, method-reference

Eclipse content assist not working when using Method reference  Stream.map

```
List<String> l1 = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" });
l1 = l1.stream().map(String::toUpperCase).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

When i press Ctr+Spae after 
`l1.stream().map(String::toUpperCase).` 
no proposal is being shown. It works fine if I use Lambda instead of method-reference.

Eclipse Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0)

Comment: Which Java version you are using?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_241"

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24453083/eclipse-luna-r-no-content-assist-for-java-8-method-references

Comment: @Shubham, that is different problem, for me content assist works fine after ::

Comment: This seems to be utterly broken, you might want to report it on Eclipse Bugzilla https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs

Comment: Did anyone ever report this? It appears to still be broken in Eclipse 2020-12.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug reported to Eclipse : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=563020

EDIT : The bug has been fixed and will be part of the 4.21 release.